# Selecting the most recent results, in ascending order

Tags: mysql

I am currently using the mysql query:
`SELECT COUNT(*), time FROM visit GROUP BY time ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 14`
to get the 14 most recent "COUNT(*)"s from a mysql database. Unfortunately, they are in backwards order.

If I replace `DESC` with `ASC` they are in the right order, but I get the 14 oldest rather than the 14 newest. How would I go about getting these in the right order? Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add an alias

```
select * from 
    (select count(*), time from visit group by time order by time desc limit 14) as t
order by time
```

Comment: Thanks! (I actually figured this out a few seconds before your answer) :)

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap it in another select:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*), time FROM visit GROUP BY time ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 14) as SUB
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Comment: That gives me: `Every derived table must have its own alias`